# How can I proof that this aplication is coercive?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the next problem. I have to proof that the aplication $a$ is coercive, defined as $$a: H \times H \longrightarrow R$$
$$ a(x,y) = 2 \int_0^1 \frac{x'y'}{1+t}dt + x(1) $$

Where $H = \{x \in H^1(0,1),x(0) = 0\} $. I also have to proof that is continous, and I did it, but I not sure that I made it in the right way. Pls HELP!!!

Comment: Pelas, can you show what have you tried? Maybe it would be useful to give  an answer

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake when i was capying the problem. I'll send the whole problem. I have to proof that exists a unique solution for the next problem: $min \{\int_0^1( \frac{|x'|^2}{1+t} -2x)dt + x(1), x \in H^1(0,1),x(0) = 0\}$. My mistake was that the bilinear form is $a(x,y) = 2\int_0^1( \frac{x'y'}{1+t})$. $x(1)$ is a part of the linear form.

Comment: For find the solution i have to use the Lax-Milgram Theorem, and i need to check the condición. That the space is a Hilbert space, but that is obvious, $a(x,y)$ is bilinear, continuous, coercive, and simetric, and that $f(y) = \int_0^1 2y(t)dt - y(1)$ is continuous